# GLib: Graceful termination of GApplication on Unix SIGINT

Tags: command-line, glib, sigint

When the user hits <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in a Posix / Linux shell with a program running, that program recieves a SIGINT signal. When running a program based on GApplication, this means that the program gets terminated immediately.

How can I overcome this and have GApplication shut down gracefully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `g_unix_signal_add()`. This function takes a callback that is called once the program recieves the signal you specify. (SIGINT in this case)

That callback should then call `g_application_release()` until the GApplication's use count dropped to zero. Once that is the case, the Main Loop will terminate and GApplication's `shutdown` signal will be emitted. By handling that signal you can do all necessary deinitialization tasks before the program will terminate.

(taken from the [reference manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GApplication.html):)

> GApplication provides convenient life cycle management by maintaining a "use count" for the primary application instance. The use count can be changed using g_application_hold() and g_application_release(). If it drops to zero, the application exits. Higher-level classes such as GtkApplication employ the use count to ensure that the application stays alive as long as it has any opened windows.

An example in Vala:

```
public class MyApplication : Application {
    public MyApplication () {
        Object (flags: ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE);

        startup.connect (on_startup);
        activate.connect (on_activate);
        shutdown.connect (on_shutdown);

        Unix.signal_add (
            Posix.SIGINT,
            on_sigint,
            Priority.DEFAULT
        );
    }

    private bool on_sigint () {
        release ();
        return Source.REMOVE;
    }

    private void on_startup () {
        print ("Startup\n");
    }

    private void on_activate () {
        print ("command line\n");
        hold ();
    }

    private void on_shutdown () {
        print ("Shutdown\n");
    }
}

void main (string[] args) {
    new MyApplication ().run ();
}
```

(compile with `valac foo.vala --pkg gio-2.0 --pkg posix`)

Comment: This will emit a critical warning if the user presses Ctrl+C a second time while the application is shutting down. You should return `GLib.SOURCE_REMOVE` from `on_sigint()` to remove the signal handler after it’s first triggered — or add some state tracking to avoid calling `release()` more times than `hold()`.